# Horizontal slide show photo gallery IOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Is there any component or API for IOS5 to easy implement a horizontal slide show photo gallery?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer

I used this one once, it's pretty easy to implement. It doesn't support arc, so you should compile it with

> -fno-objc-arc